# datePicker onSelect function not retrieving classes added before from it-self

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

here is my code

```
 onSelect: function (dateText, inst)
 {
    inst.inline = false;
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").addClass("markupDate");
 }
```

when i inspect html code,class "markupDate" was added to the html element successfully.

I select another date,and i check with my onSelect function if the date have already a "markupDate" class.if not i add it.

the problem so , that when i click into a date already having class "markupDate" and i ask with jquery if cell have class "markupDate" the result is false.

but when inspect element in chrome , $(".ui-datepicker-current-day") have already class "markupDate" !!

here is the code

```
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst)
 {
     //no markupDate class in the result !
    console.log(($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").attr("class")));
    inst.inline = false;
     /*result is ever false !*/
    if($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass("markupDate")){
    //do something
    }else{
    $(".ui-datepicker-current-day").addClass("markupDate");
  }
 }
```

the code of _selectDay in jquery-ui library is

```
    _selectDay: function (a, b, c, d) {
        var e = $(a);
        if ($(d).hasClass(this._unselectableClass) 
  ||  this._isDisabledDatepicker(e[0])) 
   return;
   /*i put my code here and i return  =>my code is working */
     var f = this._getInst(e[0]);
      f.selectedDay = f.currentDay = $("a",d).html(), f.selectedMonth = 
     f.currentMonth = b, f.selectedYear =f.currentYear = c, 
    this._selectDate(a, this._formatDate(f, f.currentDay, f.currentMonth, 
    f.currentYear))
```

when i add my code  directly inside ,and i return before this line:

```
          var f = this._getInst(e[0]);
```

onSelect function retrieve if the $(".ui-datepicker-current-day") have class "markupDate" or not.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it appears you are using haveClass instead of hasClass.

Change this

```
 if($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").haveClass("markupDate")){
```

To

```
 if($(".ui-datepicker-current-day").hasClass("markupDate")){
```

Comment: yes i'll edit my post thanks.In the prod i'am using hasClass this is'nt the problem.

Comment: Also, you don't have to check.  Calling addClass when it already has the class will not add it twice.